# Create new <select> without previous used values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got a list of available options in a first 'select' which is supposed the be the main option.
Then I want the user to choose optional options so when he choose the first option, a new select is added displaying the remaining options available.

If the user choose an optional option I want a new select to be displayed, etc until there's no more options.

The options also need (and here's my issue) to be synchronized between every select.
I've got this code:

**html**

```
<form action="">
<select name="primary" id="primary">
</select>
<br/>
<div id="optional" style="display: none">
    <button id="addField">Add field</button>
    <br/>
</div>
</form>
```

**js**

```
var counter = 0;
var selects = [];
var categories = JSON.parse('[ { "value": "", "label": "Aucune", "taken": false }, { "value": "Électronique/Électroménager", "label": "Électronique/Électroménager", "taken": false }, { "value": "Maison Jardin", "label": "Maison Jardin", "taken": false } ]');

function addField() {
    $("#optional").append("<select name='optional' id='secondary" + counter + "'></select>");
    var jid = $("#secondary" + counter);
    fill(jid);
    jid.on("click", function () {
        updateCat(jid.val());
    });
    selects.push(jid);
    counter++;
}

function fill(select) {
    console.warn("select");
    //select.empty();
    console.groupCollapsed();
    for (var cat in categories) {
        console.log(categories[cat].label + " -> " + categories[cat].taken);
        if (!categories[cat].taken) {
            select.append("<option value=" + categories[cat].value + ">" + categories[cat].label + "</option>");
        }
    }
    console.groupEnd();
}

function updateCat(cat) {
    console.warn("update "+cat);
    var catId = findCat(cat);
    if (catId != -1) {
        categories[catId].taken = true;
    }
    for (var s in selects) {
        fill(selects[s]);
    }
}

function findCat(cat) {
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        if (categories[i].label == cat) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

$(function () {
    var primary = $("#primary"), optional = $("#optional"), buttonField = $("#addField");
    fill(primary);
    selects.push(primary);
    primary.on("click", function () {
        if (primary.val() !== "") {
            updateCat(primary.val());
            optional.css("display", "block");
            buttonField.on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addField();
            });
        }
        else {
            buttonField.css("display", "none");
        }
    })
});
```

And I'm having a hard time reloading every select, because the empty function works but I lose the previous selected option. I could save it, then reload it etc, but I'm not sure if that's the right way.

Anyone got any idea how I would do something like that ?

Comment: can you use jQuery? it'll make it easier I think

Comment: let me know if the answer helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written an example for you to demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/oLtvbo24/4/)

basically the idea is when you change the dropdown, get the non selected options, create a new select, and append those options. I've also added a line to remove those options from the initial select (you can remove it if that's not what you want).

html:

```
<div id='container'>
  <select id='select-1' class='select'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var index = 2;
    $(document).on('change', '.select', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var options = $('#' + id + ' option:not(:selected)').clone();
        //$('#' + id + ' option:not(:selected)').remove();
        $('#container').append('<select id="select-' + index + '" class="select"></select>')
        $('#select-' + index).append(options);
        index++;
    });
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oLtvbo24/8/)

this will probably need some tweaking, like moving options around, but it should get you started

Comment: I tried commenting  
    $('#' + id + ' option:not(:selected)').remove();  
but it still doesn't show all the option once a select is selected. I would like it to be changed if needed.

Comment: sorry, that's because the options aren't cloned, I updated the link, click it again to try it

Comment: did that fix it for you?

Comment: That's better but my biggest issue remains: with your provided (and updated) fiddle, if I choose 'two', I've got a new select with options minus 'two' which is good. In this second select if I choose 'three' and I check the first select, three is still available. In fact I tried in my original code to have a 'None selected' option which would act like a reset and re-enable a selected option previously selected and disabled.

Comment: hmm.. I see, you want to be able to undo a select you made previously and have it reappear in the first select?

Comment: I updated the fiddle again, check it one more time, the one at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Your code helped me to re-think how I'll approach the problem (in a much easier way) so I'll accept it. Thanks for your time!